# How to configure automatic clearCache in Strapi Cache Middlware with Strapi v3?

Tags: caching, content-management-system, strapi

I have a problem related with the cache middleware in strapi v3. I have two models that are not related each other but when loading the first one I am calling the second one. So my problem is:

I have the `clearRelatedCache` attribute enable so when something change from one of each model, it refresh the cache. Everything works fine if we call each route individually. The problem is with the first model (settings) retrieving an array from the second-one (events). If I call `settings` and something is changed from `events` it does not refresh the cache of `settings`

My question is, is there any magic attribute that related `settings` with `events` only in the configuration cache so every time I change something from the `events` the cache from `settings` refresh itself?

Things that I tried: I know it can work relating each other on Strapi but I cannot do that. I know it also works configuring its afterXXX method on the model but I want do find a elegant solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.